# Странная работа у Adapter

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter

Использую `Adapter` для `RecyclerView`. И вроде все работает и показывает, но есть странность, на 15 элементе когда листаешь вниз он меняет текст(со следующих элементов), и все последующие элементы начинают повторяться по имени. То есть 16 элемент уже имеет значение 0 элемента, семнадцатый равен первому элементу. С чем это может быть связано?

Использую во фрагменте

```
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.resurs);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mAdapter = new Adapter(locationTanki.getTexnika_pokaz().getList_texnika(), getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Сам `Adapter`

```
private class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    public List<Texnika> Texnika_list;
    public Context mcontext;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public Adapter(List<Texnika> Texnika_list, Context context) {
        this.Texnika_list = Texnika_list;
        this.mcontext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a layout
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.items_texnika_pokaz_content, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        viewHolder.checkBox.setText(Texnika_list.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(Texnika_list.get(position).isVisible());

        viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                    Texnika_list.get(position).setVisible(true);
                else {
                    Texnika_list.get(position).setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Texnika_list.size();
    }

    public List<Texnika> getTexnika_list() {
        return Texnika_list;
    }
}
```

Сам `ViewHolder`

```
 public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public CheckBox checkBox;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);

        checkBox = (CheckBox) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    }
}
```

Comment: Очень советую использовать стиль при написании кода и придерживаться правил, очень тяжело читать. Прошу прощения за вопрос, но вы уверены, что в списке все правильно приходит?

Comment: @iamthevoid, хорошо учту насчет правил, вы правы. Насчет списка проверял, список правильный приходит.  Допустим я снимаю флажок на первом элементе, то это дублируется и на 16 элементе

Comment: По приведенному тут коду все должно работать. Нет возможности выложить куда нибудь проект?

Comment: @iamthevoid, https://ru.files.fm/u/jjezkqga вот добавил

Comment: !!! Не надо так делать. Вы знаете для чего нужен ресайклер вью? Не нужно хранить вью холдер в адаптере. Мне это даже в голову не пришло, пока я адаптер не переписал. Условно ресайклер - ресайклит, то есть используется одна вью для всего, она и возвращается в onBind. В памяти их хранится в момент времени столько, сколько на экране, а не по количеству элементов списка. и в новые в onBind сетятся параметры. Не надо сохранять, возвращайте в onCreateViewHolder new и все будет хорошо. Можете поискать туториалы, как раньше это делали с лист вью и посмотреть видео, тогда станет понятнее

Comment: @iamthevoid, на сайте где-то нашел это. Спасибо за ваш совет, я уже переделал и всё работает)

Answer (score -1):

Текст меняется на элементах при прокрутке, потому что в некоторых из них у вас не указан никакой текст. А так как **RecyclerView** использует элементы повторно, то старый текст бывает сохраняется. То же самое касается и флажков.

Чтобы решить проблему, перед биндом элементов выставляйте состояние полей на дефолтное.